# How to check if user is on the edit page of a custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I would like to determine if the user is on a custom post type. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How and where will you be using this?
To get the post type of a post in a the loop you can use [`get_post_type()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type)

To determine if a user is on a custom post type, like if you got multiple post types, you could check if it's no 'post' or 'page', if you want to check for a certain post type you just enter the unique custom post type name.

If this is not the answer you are looking for, please give us more info on the problem.